# Print values of dynamically allocated 2-D array using a pointer to the array Asked today

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, data-structures

I am trying to dynamically allocate a 2-D array named array and then a pointer ptr is made to point to the array. Now, when I try to print array values using the pointer, am getting garbage values when I print the array values.
I am new to pointers, so would much appreciate if someone points out where I am thinking wrongly.

The code snippet:

> ```
> int (*ptr[2])[8][512];
> int** array;
> array = (int**)malloc(8 * sizeof(int*));
>
> for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
> {
>     array[i] = (int*)malloc(512 * sizeof(int));
> }
>
> ptr[0] = (int(*)[8][512])array;
>
>
> for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
> {
>     for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
>     {
>         array[i][j] = i+j;
>         
>     }
>     
> }
> for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
> {
>     for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
>     {
>         cout<<"Val"<<((*ptr[0])[i][j])<<endl;
>         
>     }
>     
> }
> ```

Comment: what is the error? this runs online for me 
only problem i see is you are not using std

it should be std::cout and std::endl

Comment: I am getting some garbage values when I print the array values in:

cout<<"Val"<<((*ptr[0])[i][j])<<endl;

. Ideally, for [i][j], it should print i+j, but getting garbage values instead.

Comment: can you post your expected output vs current output and and error messages

Comment: Observed:

Val-490549504
Val22038
Val-490547440
Val22038
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0
Val0



Expected:

Val0
Val1
Val2
Val3
Val1
Val2
Val3
Val4
Val2
Val3
Val4
Val5
Val3
Val4
Val5
Val6
Val4
Val5
Val6
Val7
Val5
Val6
Val7
Val8
Val6
Val7
Val8
Val9
Val7
Val8
Val9
Val10

Comment: @william_,
I believe I am doing something wrong here:

ptr[0] = (int(*)[8][512])array;

I want to make ptr[0] point to the 2-D array named array but it's not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I can't get your idea about allocating memory on stack and then on heap

`int **(ptr[2]);` try this